# Best practices of structuring stored procedures

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

As a developer mainly writing c# I have adopted some good practices when writing c# code. When I sometimes write stored procedures I have trouble applying those practices to the stored procedure code.

On several occasions I have inherited nightmare stored procedure code, first three or four layers of stored procedures setting up some temp tables and mostly calling each other. No real work done and just a few lines of code. Then at last there is a call to "the final" stored procedure, a big monster of 3000-5000 lines of SQL code. That code usually have a lot of code smells like code duplication, intricate control flows (a.k.a. spaghetti) and a method that does too many things stacked after each other with no clear separation where one chunk of work starts and where it ends (not even a comment as a divisor).

I have also noticed the use of out commented select statements that selects from intermediate temp tables. The selects can be turned back on for debug purposes, but need to be removed before any calling code expecting a specific order of the returned result sets.

Apparently my fellow team mates also share my lack of good SQL writing practices.

So... ( and here comes the real question) ... what are good practices for writing modular maintainable stored procedures?

Both home made practices and references to books/blogs are welcome. Methods as well as tools that help with certain tasks.

Lets summarize some areas where I have not found good practices

- Modularization and encapsulation (is stored procedures communication via temp tables really the way to go?)

  - In c# I use assemblies, classes and methods decorated with access modifiers to accomplish this.
- Debugging/testing (better than modifying the target of debugging?)

  - Debug tools?
  - Debug traces?
  - Test fixtures?
- Emphasizing code/logic/data/control flow using code the structure of the code

  - In c# I refactor and break out smaller methods that does just one logical task each.
- Code duplication

Mostly I encounter SQL Server as DBMS but DBMS agnostic answers or answers pointing out features of other DBMS:es that help in above cases are also welcome.

To give some background: Most large stored procedures I have encountered are in reporting scenarios where the base is to just create some summary values from a large table. But along the way you need to exclude some of the values that happen to be in some exception table, add some of the values in some not yet completed stuff table, compare with last year (can you imagine the ugly code that handles products changing department between years?), etc.

Comment: For these reasons as well as inability to use stored procedures with SCM, I've avoided them for all but the most necessary and obvious uses (triggers, etc...).  We keep the business logic in the business layer (.NET) and use the database for just that -- a data base.

Comment: Ideally, stored procedures should not call other stored procedures. That's what the BL layer is for. Unfortunately, that sentiment doesn't really help if you already have a database full of nested SP calls. Are you looking for advice on how to make the current model more maintainable, or advice on how to refactor your system to better follow best practices?

Comment: @gahooa I put as much as possible in .NET too (partly because that is my home arena) but on some occasions, like when inheriting a large code base or when you have huge amounts of data you are more or less stuck with stored procedures.

Comment: I feel very strongly that you should treat your database as a service with a boundary just as you treat your classes in .NET.  i.e. it has a well defined interface and guarantee about the integrity of what it provides.  Stored procedures under version control and limited or no access to base tables is a very important part of that.  As many constraints as possible are applied at the database layer to ensure that the database is able to meet it's guarantees.  If you use a database as a dumb set of tables, that's about all you will get.

Comment: @cade Roux, I'd upvote you comment a million times if I could. The use of a database as a dumb store is the mark of an amateur database designer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I write a lot of complex stored procs. Some things I would consider best practices:

Don't use dynamic SQl in a stored proc unless you are doing a search proc with lots of parameters which may or may not be needed (then it is currently one of the best solutions). If you must use dynamic SQl in a proc always have a debug input parameter and if the debug parameter is set, then print the SQL statement created rather than executing it. This will save hours of debugging time!

If you are performing more than one action query in a proc (insert/update/delete), use Try Cacth blocks and transaction processing. Add a test parameter to the input parameters and when it is is set to 1, always rollback the entire transaction. Before rolling back in test mode, I usually have a section that returns the values in the tables I'm affecting to ensure that what I think I am doing to the database is in fact what I did do. Or you could have checks as go as shown below. That is as simple as putting in the following code around your currently commented out selects (and uncommenting them) once you have the @test parameter.

```
If @test =1
Begin
Select * from table1 where field1 = @myfirstparameter
End
```

Now you don't have to go through and comment and uncomment each time time you test.

@test or @debuig should always be set with a default value of 0 and placed last in the list. That way adding them won't break existing calls of the proc.

Consider having  logging and/or error logging tables for procs doing inserts/updates/deletes. If you record the the steps and or errors in table variables as you go, they are still available after a rollback to be inserted into the logging table.  Knowing what part of a complex proc failed and what the error was can be invaluable later on.

Where possible do not nest stored procs.  If you need to run multiple records in a loop, replace the stored proc with one that has a table-valued parameter and set up the proc to run in a set-based and not individual record fashion.  This will work if the table-valued parameter has one record or many records.

If you have a complex select with a lot of subqueries or derived tables, consider using CTEs instead. Refactor any correlated subqueries or cursors to better performing set-based code. Always think in terms of sets of data not one record.

Do not, under any conceivable circumstance, nest views. The performance hit is much worse than any small amount of saved development time. And trust me, nested views do not save maintenance time when the change needs to be to the view the furthest into the chain of views.

All stored procs (and other database code) should be in source control.

Table variables are good for smaller data sets, but temp tables (real ones that start with # or ## not staging tables)  can be better for performance in large data sets. If using temp tables drop them when you don't need them anymore. Try to avoid the use of global temp tables.

Learn to write performant SQL. It is usually just as easy to write SQL that will perform well than SQL which will not once you know the techiniques. If you write complex stored procs, there is no excuse for not knowing which techniques work better than which other ones. Learn how to make sure your query is sargable. Avoid cursors, correlated subqueries, scalar functions and other things which run row-by-agonizing-row.

Comment: RE nested views: I inherited a system with nested views, and on doing performance investigation on SQL Server it didn't cause any problem.  Maybe it used to be an issue, but in MSSQL 2008 and above the query planner is pretty smart and effectively just inlines the view.

Comment: The server we had the issue with this on was a SQl Server 2008 server. T may depend on how tehw veiws are written. The other problem we had was the views became ridiculously hard to maintain and eventually we actually hit the hard limit of the system and the views couldn't run at all. I stand by what I said, it is a bad practice to use views to call other views.

Answer (score 7):

Communication via temp tables is sometimes a huge code smell.  Such procedures often cannot be run by a user without interfering with each other (if you re-use a temp table name for different procedures' ins and outs and they aren't re-created or if you use the same name with two different table schemas).  They can be hard to troubleshoot - like any feature, use them when necessary and better alternatives don't exist.  Using real tables temporarily can also be problematic.

Stored procs which pass data to each other in SQL Server at all (more than parameters) can be problematic.  There are table-valued parameters now and many things which previously would have been done with procs can now be done with inline table-valued functions or (and usually preferred over) multi-statement table-valued functions.

In SQL Server, avoid heavy use of scalar functions and multi-statement table-valued function on large rowsets - they do not perform very well, so modular techniques which may seem obvious in C# don't really apply here.

I would recommend you look at [Ken Henderson's Guru's Guide to SQL Server Stored Procedures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201700468) - published in 2002, it still has a wealth of useful information on database application design.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding, but temp tables can be run with multiple users without issues.  But maybe you're talking about a special case?

Comment: @Mark SQLDev You are correct - local temp tables are connection-local - I find temp tables (and table variables) difficult to debug.  And, of course, you are making decisions about what to materialize and when instead of leaving it to the optimizer.  And you need to keep track of the naming so that it doesn't clash etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is such a good question. As a C# dev myself having to dabble in SQL it seems SQL by its very nature gets in the way of the best-practices I'm used to with C#.

Common Table Expresions are great to isolate queries in a stored procedure but you can only use them once! That leads you to define views but then you've lost your encapsulation.

A resultset from one stored procedure are very difficult to use in another so you might be tempted to write table-valued functions. That adds to your permissions-maintenance burden and forces you to write functions 'twice' - once as a function and another as a procedure that calls the function. Otherwise, you have different interfaces to your DAL depending on whether it's a procedure or not.

All of this has caused me, over time, to stick to simple CRUD stored procedures (that do not call each other) in the database and few, isolated, queries when the relationships are complex. More BI-stuff. Everything else is in the BLL.

Physically, SQL is isolated in seperate files by function or the table they revolve around and managed in source control.

Avoid SELECT * and favor specifying columns. That saves you from run-time problems when you change a table and don't touch all the procs. Yes, there is a recompile for procs but it WILL miss some, especially if views are involved. Plus, SELECT * almost always returns more columns than you really need and that's a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: SQL best practices definitly are not the same as what you are used to with C#. Trying to use c# best practices in the relational world is one of the causes of badly performing databases. Databases are designed to maximize performance not to make maintainability easier.

Comment: And you can use temp tables instead of CTEs when you need to use them more than once in a proc.

Answer (score 1):

The comments above are great advice of Do's and Dont's when it comes to SQL code writing. If I understand your questions correctly, you are asking if this is normal for SQL Developer to write hundreds even thousands of code in a single stored procedure.  In C# this is a big no-no.  You are to encapsulate logic into small chucks using methods, assemblies, and classes.  SQL Developer tend to write the entire logic in one stored procedure to accomplish a relating task; as HLGEM mentioned above, "If possible, do not nest stored procedures". Do not nest Views.

For example:  A simple Get and Insert design in C# looks like this:

- Call GetData Method
- Call Get Data Method
- Call Transform Data Method

  - Call CheckAlphaNumeric Method
  - Call Data Enrichment Method
- Call Load Transform**ed** Data Method

A SQL developer will design it like this:
In a single stored proc:

- Get Data and Transform using either temp table or table variable, then Load it into the final table.

If you are to change the way SQL is written to match the writing structure of C# Developer, you would then do this:

- Execute Main Stored Procedure (which calls the below sproc.)

  - Execute GetData Stored Procedure and load into Stage Table
  - Execute Transform Stored Procedure which read the Stage Table and transform data
  - Execute Load Data stored procedure to load Stag**ed** or Transformed data into final table.